# Refresh header.phtml on click on add to cart button

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, header

I am making a Free Shipping top bar, i have added code in **header.phtml** which is located in `app/design/frontend/mytheme/mytheme05/template/page/html/header.phtml`

My Code is :

```
<div id= "um" class="container" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; ">
<?php

$grand= $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()); 

$count = (int) filter_var($grand, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$umer= 1500;
$total= $umer-$count;
if ($count < $umer)
{
    echo "Free Shipping on $total";
}

else 
    echo "Free Shipping Enjoy"; 
//var_dump($count)

?>
```

I want to refresh this div when **Add to cart** Button is press.

The code is located in :

`app/design/frontend/mytheme/mytheme05/template/magiccart/magicproduct/product/grid.phtml`

Code is here`

```
<div class="actions-cart">
<?php if(in_array("cart", $actions)):?>
    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Umer') ?></span></span></button>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to refresh that div on onclick Button.

How I can do this ?

[image: This is the Header which I want to update. It is working fine if I refresh the page]

Comment: The better is to do it with Ajax, now you want to do it with Ajax or even if you reload the page does not bother you ?

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can do with this Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this on reload the page, you have to add `location.reload();` on `onclick` add to cart button, But i confirm that the best way is to do it with `AJAX`

For the product page for exemple:

`app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="btn-cart btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this); location.reload();"><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></button>
```

**With Ajax :**

```
function reload(url){
       $.get(url, function(data){      // $.get will get the content of the page defined in url and will return it in **data** variable 
            $('#row').append(data);
       }
    }

$('.button.btn-cart').click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = 'http://example.com/somepage.html';
        reload(url);  // this calls the reload function
});
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19889100/ajax-reload-div-content-on-click-button)

Or you can do some `load()` function something like :

```
$("#myDiv").load(location.href+" #myDiv>*","");
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18490026/refresh-reload-the-content-in-div-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: I want to only refresh that free shipping part which is in header instead of whole page

Comment: Look my update please

Comment: you're welcome ;)